# CS0103: The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

I've created the following function backend:

```
public string getImageURL()
{
    return "some text";
}
```

Within my FormView , I have the following code;

```
<img class="hotelImage floatLeft" src="<% getImageURL(); %>" alt="" />
```

But I keep getting the CS0103: error. Why is that?
I'm pretty sure I've called lots of functions this way in the past.

**Update**
heh..... this is a bit embarrassing. I discovered I was working on a backup file which is not in use in the solution.... I had opened it to look at some old code... so guess what happened when I added the function to the correct file....

Comment: can you list the exact message please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img class="hotelImage floatLeft" src="<%= getImageURL() %>" alt="" />
```

Comment: @Steven: are you sure you added the = sign after the % and removed the semi-colon? This works for me.

Comment: heh..... this is a bit embarrassing. I discovered I was working on a backup file which is not in use in the solution.... I had opened it to look at some old code... so guess what happened when I added the function to the correct file....

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is have the URL come from the code-behind, you can just use a protected member instead.

```
protected string imageUrl = "Some text";
```

Then in the ASPX you can use

```
<%= imageUrl %>
```

to get the desired string.